# How to change files outside of Xcode: SVN doesn't seem to pick up change

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn

My iOS project is setup with SVN.  When making changes inside Xcode there are no issues, I can commit and update.

However I also need to make changes to external files using another application.  These external files are needed by the iOS app and need to be in the project tree.  However I cannot get SVN to pick up the changes so that I can commit the changes.

What I have been doing is editing the external files and then copying the file over the referenced file using finder and then going into Xcode but it doesn't update and see it as modified.

I have also tried removing the file in Xcode and adding it again doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're operating in an SVN environment, you need to use the svn command line tools (such as "svn move") when moving/renaming a file. In essence, if you simply copy over the file in the Finder, svn doesn't know it's been modified.

Is there no way you can simply edit the file in-place using the external tool?